# jQuery tooltip plugin to use a dynamic title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

Background: I would like a better replacement for the default `title` tag tooltip, one that would at least allow me multiple lines across all browsers. The problem is that the `title` tag gets updated once per second.

Is there a JavaScript/jQuery plugin that can be attached to an element, and update itself as the `title` attribute changes? I guess it shouldn't be that hard to implement from scratch, but there is no need to reinvent things.

Comment: You may consider this: http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/

Comment: @MunimAbdul: tried that one, but it fetches the `title` attribute only once, during init. If the attribute is empty during init, tooltip will stay blank whenever I hover the element, even if I change `title` contents afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would be overkill for you cause, but I use this jQuery plugin: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

In my opinion it's the best tooltip plugin out there.

Every time our title changes you could use one of its events (`render()` maybe).

Comment: qTip2 also loads the title element during init, and removes it from the parent element. But I may be able to pass the `render` callback you've mentioned, so I will check this option.